# Can I enforce SQL Server explicitly NOT to CACHE my query result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there an explicit **command** or so **to enforce** SQL Server **not to 'CACHE'** my query **results**?

I am working on a performance issue and when a long query is finished on the 2nd call it takes too fast, **in order to compare query performances** when I make modifications, I want this behavior to not to take place.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong. Use precise measurements instead: enable [`SET STATISTICS IO ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx) and [`SET STATISTICS TIME ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx) and then compare the queries. Look at the number of *logical reads* your queries have, this would be the driving factor to improve performance.

If you force a cold cache (which is possible) you are optimizing for the *wrong* case, since most times your production server will be warmed up and serving data form the buffer pool.

Also the fact that you are seeing significant IO driven by the query first time is a clear indication of table scans. Query rewrite may help, but your real problem much more likely to be is missing indexes and that's what you should focus on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You will want to check this out: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1360/clearing-cache-for-sql-server-performance-testing/.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are referring to the caching of your query result vs. the execution plan?

Electing not to cache execution plans can be done at an object level using:

```
WITH RECOMPILE
```

Worth checking out: [The Use and Abuse of RECOMPILE in SQL Server (Video)](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/06/use-abuse-of-recompile-sql-server-video/).